# FPS on WinForms

Tags: winforms, frame-rate

I write WinForms Application and I want to draw FPS on each of it. Is there any way to get it from window or get number of frames used to draw window in 1 sec?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make much sense. Winforms uses GDI+ as a graphics engine, which does not mainting a constant redraw loop. Windows are only redrawn as needed when they are invalidated for any reason.

You can use a `System.Diagnostics.StopWatch` to measure how long a single iteration of painting takes.

The inverse of this value is the theoretical frame rate you can achieve.

Comment: Thanks, I just start working with windows forms and I really dont know a lot about it.